# Are there games that sync across devices through iCloud / Game Center?

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, games

With iOS 5 and iCloud i was hoping that games would get synced across devices. If I'm playing a game on my iPad and then later pick up the same game on my iPhone, then i would like to be able to start right where i left off on my other device. Are there any games that currently do this? Or is this even currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Starbase Orion](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/starbase-orion/id438375580?mt=8) was one of the first ones out that synced all local games through iCloud. There are of course many, many others, so the answer is Yes - this exist by design and developers can make use of it as long as their data fits within the storage requirements of iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

[Pocket Planes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pocket-planes/id491994942?mt=8) does this very well, and [Doodle Jump](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doodle-jump/id307727765?mt=8) does, but that's mostly for scores and settings, not the game itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Scribblenaughts Remix](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/scribblenauts-remix/id444844790?mt=8) does this, I have played on iPad where I left off on iPhone